# Loop Through Table Column and Create New Values in Next Column Based on Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that has 4 columns:

- ID
- keyword
- Component
- NewComponent

The first 3 contain data and the last one does not.

I have the data sorted by keyword then by component.

Looking at the image below:

Original Table:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

So as far as I can see, two loops need to be done:

1. Loop through keyword
2. While looping through keyword, loop through components and create new ones

This is the code I have so far, but I have confused myself with all the loops already..

```
    Sub SingleColumnTable_To_Array()

    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim compArr() As String, kwArr(), newArr()

    Set tmpltWkbk = Workbooks("New DB.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = tmpltWkbk.Sheets("TableSheet")

    Set myTable = ws1.ListObjects("KW_Table")

    counterOne = 0

    myArray = myTable.DataBodyRange

    kwCounter = 1

    'keywords
    For y = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)

        counterTwo = counterTwo + 1
        ReDim Preserve kwArr(counterTwo)
        kwArr(counterTwo) = myArray(y, 23)

    Next y

    RemoveDupesDict kwArr, newArr

    'components
    For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)

        counterOne = counterOne + 1
        ReDim Preserve compArr(counterOne)
        compArr(counterOne) = myArray(x, 3)

    Next x

    For Each kwElement In newArr

        For Each compElement In compArr

            Counter = 1

            Do While kwCounter < Application.CountIf(kwArr, kwElement) + 1

                'This is how I imagine I would create the new component name
                'Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = compElement & "." & Counter

                Counter = Counter + 1

                kwCounter = kwCounter + 1

            Loop

            End If

        Next compElement

    Next kwElement

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't see why you couldn't do this with a COUNTIFS formula?

Comment: @SJR Thank you for the reply.. No specific reason really, now that you mention it.. There's +- 14000 rows of data across multiple sheets which I need to do the same thing with, didn't think a simple formula would be the way to go.

Comment: @SJR, I think using a formula would run into a problem in terms of the decimal increment. For each component, the decimal increment needs to start over at 1 when working with a new keyword.

Comment: What about `=C2&"."&COUNTIFS($B$2:B2,B2,$C$2:C2,C2)` ? Could add using VBA if desired.

Comment: @SJR I will give this a try quick :)

Comment: Aaaaand it's working brilliantly! :) Thank you @SJR. Not sure if you would like to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment above. Expanded code slightly to add a new column to a table and insert the formula in case you want a VBA solution:

```
Sub x()

Dim t As ListObject

Set t = Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table1")

t.ListColumns.Add
t.ListColumns(t.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).DataBodyRange.Formula = "=C2&"".""&COUNTIFS($B$2:B2,B2,$C$2:C2,C2)"

End Sub
```

Comment: It's my pleasure. Of course those 2s in the formula would need changing if your table doesn't start in row 1.